# fftw_complex from C to python with CFFI

Tags: python, c, fftw, python-cffi

Question: I want to return results in `C` from `FFTW` to `Python`. The results are stored in the type `fftw_complex`. How do I do?

Background: I am working with `Cmake`, trying to call upon `FFTW` through `C` and then pass the results to `Python`. I do this to learn the basics of `Cmake`. Below I have a function, `int example_FFT(int NUM_POINTS)`, which does FFT on a sequence with length `NUM_POINTS`. The sequence is of type `fftw_complex`, which is a struct that holds pairs of real and imaginary numbers. In my case are all real parts equal to 1, the imaginary part equal to 0.

I can compile with `Cmake` and pass the test test.py, in `Python`, successfully.

test.py:

```
import pytest
from example import ffi, lib

def test_transform_ones():
    NUM_POINTS = int(4);
    assert lib.example_FFT(NUM_POINTS) == 4.0
```

c-code:

```
int example_FFT(int NUM_POINTS) {
   fftw_complex signal[NUM_POINTS];
   fftw_complex result[NUM_POINTS];

   fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(NUM_POINTS,
                                     signal,
                                     result,
                                     FFTW_FORWARD,
                                     FFTW_ESTIMATE);

   generate_signal(signal);//Set all real values to one. Imag to 0.
   fftw_execute(plan);

   fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

   return result[0][0];
}
```

I am quite new to C and apologize for not being more precise in my problem formulation.